# WPF application - listening method is not triggered when event action is called

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, action

I have a WPF MVVM application. I have a class called `MainWindowViewModel` and a class called `TileMenuViewModel`, both of which derive from a `BaseViewModel`. All the base does is implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, while holding a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` of errors for validation.

In my `MainWindowViewModel`, I instantiate an instance of

`private TileMenuViewModel _tileMenuViewModel = new TileMenuViewModel();`

In my `TileMenuViewModel`, I have a 
`public event Action NavToCampaings = new delegate {};`

Now in the `MainWindowViewModel` constructor, I subscribe to this event:

`_tileMenuViewModel.NavToCampaings += OnNavToCampaigns;`

However, when I call the event from the `TileMenuViewModel` at some point, like `NavToCampaigns();` my subscribed event (`OnNavToCampaigns` of `MainWindowViewModel`) does not get called. When I debug with breakpoints, I can see that the `NavToCampaigns();` event Action is called, but its value is null. The debugger also does not enter the `TileMenuViewModel` when passing through the MainWindowViewModel construction where I am instantiating the `TileMenuViewModel`. However, rest of my program works as I intend and I see the Tile Menu working.

For the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? For brevity, here are my three classes:

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Main
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _windowsUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        private TileMenuViewModel _tileMenuViewModel = new TileMenuViewModel();
        private CmpCampaignListViewModel _cmpCampaignListViewModel = new CmpCampaignListViewModel();
        private NapTransferCampaignListViewModel _ntCampaignListViewModel = new NapTransferCampaignListViewModel();

        public string WindowsUser { get { return _windowsUser; } }
        public string WindowTitle { get; set; }

        private BaseViewModel _currentViewModel;

        public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel
        {
            get { return _currentViewModel; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _currentViewModel, value); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            WindowTitle = String.Format("MyApp - {0}", WindowsUser);
            NavCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnNav);
            AddNewCmpCampaignCommand = new RelayCommand(OnAddNewCmpCampaign);
            CurrentViewModel = _tileMenuViewModel;
            _tileMenuViewModel.NavToCampaings += OnNavToCampaigns;

        }

        public RelayCommand<string> NavCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand AddNewCmpCampaignCommand { get; private set; }

        public void OnNav(string destination)
        {
            switch (destination)
            {
                case "CmpCampaignList":
                    CurrentViewModel = _cmpCampaignListViewModel;
                    break;
                case "NtCampaignList":
                    CurrentViewModel = _ntCampaignListViewModel;
                    break;
                case "TileMenu":
                    CurrentViewModel = _tileMenuViewModel;
                    break;
                default:
                    CurrentViewModel = _tileMenuViewModel;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void OnAddNewCmpCampaign()
        {
            var editCampaignWindow = new AddEditCmpCampaignWindow();
            editCampaignWindow.Show();
        }

        private void OnNavToCampaigns()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = _cmpCampaignListViewModel;
            //OnNav("CmpCampaignList");
        }
    }
}
```

**TileMenuViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Main
{
    public class TileMenuViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public TileMenuViewModel()
        {
            NavToCampaignsCommand = new RelayCommand(OnNavToCampaigns);
        }

        public RelayCommand NavToCampaignsCommand { get; private set; }
        public event Action NavToCampaings = delegate { };

        private void OnNavToCampaigns()
        {
            NavToCampaings();
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Infrastructure
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(
            );

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged = delegate { };

        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get { return _errors.Count > 0; }
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            return _errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? _errors[propertyName] : null;
        }

        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val,
            [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!object.Equals(member, val))
            {
                member = val;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            ValidateProperty(propertyName, val);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void ValidateProperty<T>(string propertyName, T value)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(this);
            context.MemberName = propertyName;
            Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, results);

            if (results.Any())
            {
                _errors[propertyName] = results.Select(c => c.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                _errors.Remove(propertyName);
            }

            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I solved why it was not working: I had a new instantiation of `TileMenuViewModel` in the view that I used it for; I forgot it there after I used the viewmodel for tests. It was setting the `DataContext` to a new instance where the event was fired and `MainWindowViewModel` was listening to the event of its own instance of `TileMenuViewModel`. So I simply removed the line:

```
DataContext = new TileMenuViewModel();
```

from my `TileMenuView` and got my event wired up. I'll leave the thread here for anyone that might find this useful.

I'd still like to know if using the event as static would be a better or worse idea here though?

**Original Answer:**

I solved this finally by marking the event static. i.e:

`public static event Action NavToCampaings = delegate { };`

and of course, I subscribe to the event without using class instance:

`TileMenuViewModel.NavToCampaings += OnNavToCampaigns;`

However, I'd still like to know why I couldn't get this event system to work with the event as the instance member; and if using the event static would pose any problems (or if it is simply a bad practice?)

Any explanation would be appriceated.